# Find the odd one out

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I've been trying to work this for a while and I believe the odd one is the 4th figure, but don't seem to find a satisfying justification for this. Any help?

[image]

Few observations:
1) Bottom two dots seem to toggle left and right *together*.
2) Top items are doing a more complicated movement.

Comment: Top items seem to be moving leftward, coming back in from the right if they go out of the picture. Your answer looks correct with that logic

Comment: These things are always subjective.  The first one is the only one in which the open circle isn't paired with a closed one, so I vote for that one.  Almost certainly not what the people who posed the problem wanted, of course.

Comment: Yeah I feel the same, subjective problems are always confusing and scary. And yes I see why you think it could be the first figure. This is not about finding the next figure, so I'm also leaning toward the first one now..

Comment: But if you drop the fourth one, then the top dots just rotate cyclically to the left, and the bottom dots are always under the lone dot on top, so that works too.  Like i say, it's more a matter of taste then it is about math.

Comment: The first one is also the only one that doesn't have its mirror image among the choices.

Comment: @Jens nice observation! 2, 4 are mirror images of each other. And 3, 5 are mirror images of each other. More support for 1 being the odd one! Thank you:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with the first. All the others have a bigger circle and a smaller dot together on one side of the "numerator".

Comment: Also the two dots below the line are always on the opposite side of where the circle is, except for the first one.

Comment: Mike and @aromis you both have very good eyes! Wish I could make these observations on my own too... Ty so much :)